# Converting a file into a list and then into a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm working with a file right now where every line of data is sorted like " Dog 15 28 0 58 79 01" and I'm trying to convert it to a dictionary where Dog is the key and the others are the values.

Because its not split by comma's I've figured out that I should probably .split it to convert it to a list then use a for each loop to set the values in the dictionary but i'm struggling with the execution. This is all in python by the way. How might I go about doing it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add 1) the code you have written so far 2) the result you get 3) the result you expect instead with an exact output of the dict that should be created. Before you proceed, I suggest you read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple values for a single a key. There is always a key-value pair. A single key can only have a single value.

Edit:
According to the comment, you can do it like this

```
data = "Dog 15 28 0 58 79 01"

d = {}
d[data.split(" ")[0]] = data.split(" ")[1:]
```

Edit:
For every line in the file you can do it like

```
l = []
#if f is the file
for line in f:
    l.append({line.split(" ")[0]: line.split(" ")[1:]}) 
#It will append all the dicts into the list l
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: You're completely right, I made a mistake in the description. The value would be a list and the key would be the first word in the line.

Comment: How would I go about doing so for every line in the file? Wouldn't I have to make a list with each line existing as a single index? Would I then try to do a for loop through the list and make the dictionary based on the previous list? I apologize for bothering you so much, I'm just confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to split a line and add it to a dictionary :

```
data = "Dog 15 28 0 58 79 01"

theDict = {}
key = data.split(" ")[0]
values = data.split(" ")[1:]
theDict[key] = values
```

I hope it help you.